# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function register_widget()

Tags: php, wordpress

Im using Wordpress and I have this error :

```
    [29-Mar-2021 16:21:12 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function register_widget() in /home/nouvellexl/www/wp-includes/widgets.php:1756
Stack trace:
#0 /home/nouvellexl/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(292): wp_widgets_init('')
#1 /home/nouvellexl/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(316): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#2 /home/nouvellexl/www/wp-includes/plugin.php(484): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#3 /home/nouvellexl/www/wp-settings.php(565): do_action('init')
#4 /home/nouvellexl/www/wp-config.php(86): require_once('/home/nouvellex...')
#5 /home/nouvellexl/www/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home/nouvellex...')
#6 /home/nouvellexl/www/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home/nouvellex...')
#7 /home/nouvellexl/www/index.php(22): require('/home/nouvellex...')
#8 {main}
```

If you have some idea... I did nothing for having this error. No new plugin or nothing.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To safely use `register_widget` only use it in a callback for the `widgets_init` action:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', function(){
    register_widget( 'My_Widget' );
});
```

If the code calling this isn't your, you'll probably want to contact the plugin/theme author and have them update their code. More information can be found in the [official docs on widgets](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API).

Comment: thank you I don't know if it is the "good" answer but it helps

Comment: @LienLien, in the absence of code or a controlled scenario for reproduction, this is the best answer possible. If you provide more insight into your scenario it is possible that a deeper dive could be done. For instance, you say you did nothing, but did you host do something? Maybe they updated PHP without you knowing? Also, do you have WordPress auto-updates enabled? Thirdly, is this on every page of your site, only certain pages, or only in the admin backend?

Comment: I dont know if hoster has updated php version, I will call tomorrow (it is night now). Changing php version can make wordpress bugging ? The error is on every page of the site and wp-admin too... I dont know which portion of code I can give

Comment: Often newer versions of PHP make things that were once warnings into errors, however in this case, that should have always been an error. My instinct is telling me that possibly a plugin was updated. WordPress has an [official plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/) that you can install to perform [advanced troubleshooting](https://make.wordpress.org/support/handbook/appendix/troubleshooting-using-the-health-check/#troubleshooting). I can't tell you the parts of code to post either, but this should hopefully tell you where the problem is coming from.

Comment: How can I use this plugin if my website doesn't work ?

Comment: Ah, good point being a fatal error. Diving deeper into your specific error, assuming you are on the latest WordPress, take a look at the file `wp-includes/widgets.php` and see if the function `register_widget` exists on line 112 and make sure it is identical to the [core version](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/dc4de0d5a5360d6799985d54c8ad12f0ffe7da43/wp-includes/widgets.php#L112)

Comment: The function exists and it is the same as the core function